# how to use gevent local module

Tags: python, python-2.7, gevent

I'm trying to use gevent.local module to have a greenlet context.
Following the example in: http://www.gevent.org/gevent.local.html
I tried this sample code:

```
#!env python

import gevent
from gevent import local

def foo():
    print("IN FOO")
    data = local.local()
    data.numbers = 42

    bar()

def bar():
    print("IN BAR")
    data = local.local()
    print(data.numbers)


def main():
    foo_gl = gevent.Greenlet(foo)
    print("starting foo")
    foo_gl.start()
    gevent.joinall([foo_gl])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

But I get an error:

```
$ mytest/local.py
starting foo
IN FOO
IN BAR
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/.virtualenvs/sorites/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/greenlet.py", line 327, in run
    result = self._run(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "gl_test/local.py", line 11, in foo
    bar()
  File "gl_test/local.py", line 16, in bar
    print(data.numbers)
  File "/Users/me/.virtualenvs/sorites/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/local.py", line 186, in __getattribute__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'local' object has no attribute 'numbers'
<Greenlet at 0x1053b2410: foo> failed with AttributeError
```

What am I missing here? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you declare the variable `data` in the function `foo()`, it will be recognized as a local variable which can not be used in another function.

And the variable `data` declared in the function `bar()` is an another local variable, which has nothing to do with the variable `data` declared in the function `foo()`

**Code**

```
#!env python

import gevent
from gevent import local

def foo():
    print("IN FOO")
    data = local.local()
    #This line of code declares data as a local variable.
    data.numbers = 42

    bar()

def bar():
    print("IN BAR")
    data = local.local()
    #This line of code declares data as an another local variable.
    print(data.numbers)


def main():
    foo_gl = gevent.Greenlet(foo)
    print("starting foo")
    foo_gl.start()
    gevent.joinall([foo_gl])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The following is the code which shows that how the `gevent.local` module works.

You can find out that even the variable `data` is declared as a global variable, it will not be affected in one greenlet when you modified the same variable in another greenlet. That means you can use the variable as a local variable in each greenlet without declaring it as a local variable again.

Hope it helps.

**Modified Code**

```
#!env python

import gevent
from gevent import local

data = local.local()
data.numbers = 12
#Declare data as a global variable.

def foo():
    print("IN FOO")
    data.numbers = 42
    #Change the value of data.numbers.

    print(data.__dict__)
    #Check the values in data in the function foo.

def bar():
    print("IN BAR")

    print(data.__dict__)
    #Check the values in data in the function bar.


def main():
    print("In Main")
    print(data.__dict__)
    #Check the values in data at beginning.

    foo_gl = gevent.Greenlet(foo)
    bar_gl = gevent.Greenlet(bar)
    foo_gl.start()
    bar_gl.start()
    gevent.joinall([foo_gl, bar_gl])

    print("Afeter all, In Main")
    print(data.__dict__)
    #Check the values in data at the end.

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```